# Manage Data with React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

I am trying to build a new react app and I have some question about the architecture.

I have 2 components:

- Adress
- CreditCard

Each Component has several inputs and api functions to get the data and also to update it.

When I use both components in one Page, how can I trigger an update for both components?

Page

- Address
- CreditCard
- Submit Button

The Submit Button should trigger the Update function and wait until both are finished.
I tried to give a function from the Page to the child components via props, but I think this is the wrong way.

Comment: Could you please post the code (or a summary) showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Redux

For complex interactions between different components you can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). Redux holds the state of your entire application and can only be updated with `actions`.
An action will trigger a `reducer`. A reducer returns a new version of the state with what ever update you set there.

Treat redux some what like a database, do not store things multiple times and keep a good [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). There's an awesome library that lets you aggregate and manipulate data called [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

### Reselect

This library will let you take several parts of the store and combine them for your needs in any given scenario.

## Conclusion

To conclude, these's libraries are part of a stack I've been using for about 2.5 years (reselect only 1 year). I've found them very powerful for handling complex data. That being said there are other options like graphql, apollo or relay.